# How to get official page from a merged page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'll explain the question with an example: the facebook page "the eagles" is now merged with the official band page "Eagles" (https://www.facebook.com/EaglesBand); if a user has a "like" on "the eagles" and I retrieve it through facebook connect, how can I get the new, official, page? The APIs still provides the old page name and id.

Thanks.